# Google Chrome New Tab Page Can't Create a Link to chrome://apps

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Google Chrome Extension called SearchTab (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/searchtab/ehakebjpbbcppbapabbkomdinmnjppjh)

I'm trying to add a link to chrome://apps, but its not allowing the redirect. I checked the console and I got this error: Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://apps/

Here is my html:

```
<a href="chrome://apps"><img class="apps" src="images/chrome-apps.png"/></a>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
$('.apps').click(function () {
    window.location.replace("chrome://apps/");
});
```

I think there must be some permission I need to add to my manifest, but I don't know which one.

My manifest:

```
{
    "background": {
      "persistent": false,
      "scripts": [ "script/background.js" ]
    },
    "chrome_url_overrides": {
      "newtab": "dashboard.html"
    },
    "description": "Upgrade Your New Tab Page To SearchTab",
    "icons": {
      "16": "images/icons/icon16.jpg",
      "48": "images/icons/icon48.jpg",
      "128": "images/icons/icon128.jpg"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "searchTab",
    "offline_enabled": true,
    "permissions": ["unlimitedStorage", "tabs"],
    "version": "0.0.7"
}
```

Comment: chrome://apps does not function on Chrome OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since that you're not allowed allowed to load local resources with external JavaScript scripts, you'll have to use the `chrome.tabs` API. You can `.create()` a new tab or `.update()` an existing one.

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: "chrome://apps/", active: true});

// or:

chrome.tabs.update(/*tabId*/, {url: "chrome://apps/"});
```

Comment: Please don't create answers in clear duplicates. Vote to close instead. The question will be locked down anyway.